# Filebeat - Read from remote directory

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Is it possible to set file beat to read from remote directory (Since I can't install the process on that machine)

I've set it up this way on the beats yml:

```
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
    # Each - is a prospector. Below are the prospector specific configurations
    -
      paths:
        - \\remotemachine\remotedir\*\*.log
      input_type: log
      document_type: RemoteLogs
```

Doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

> We do not recommend reading log files from network volumes. Whenever
>   possible, install Filebeat on the host machine and send the log files
>   directly from there. Reading files from network volumes (especially on
>   Windows) can have unexpected side effects. For example, changed file
>   identifiers may result in Filebeat reading a log file from scratch
>   again.

[Filebeat Reference » Troubleshooting » Frequently asked questions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/faq.html#filebeat-network-volumes)

Answer (score 1):

it's not working like this.

it's recommend installing Filebeat on the remote servers/directory. Using shared folders is not supported!

The typical setup is that you have a Logstash + Elasticsearch + Kibana in a central place (one or multiple servers) and Filebeat installed on the remote machines from where you are collecting data.